Variable selection for checking casual relationship of regression model: should or should not?
I am looking for documents and online sources to understand whether or not I should exclude variables from my model through model selection (variable selection).
I also tried to use methods of Least Absolute Shrinkage and Selection Operator (LASSO), Akaike information criterion (AIC, for all possible subsets), Bayesian information criterion (BIC, for all possible subsets), Bayesian Model Averaging (BMA), statistically equivalent signature (SES) for my model selection.
My model has six variables.
There are two main schools of thoughts.
One is we should not exclude variables. The sources are below:
Is it worthwhile to use LASSO for variable selection even if it is cumbersome?
Causal Inference After Feature Selection
A more definitive discussion of variable selection
https://www.reddit.com/r/statistics/comments/16x3266/q_variable_selection_for_causal_inference/?rdt=43830
https://discourse.datamethods.org/t/model-selection-and-assessment-of-model-fit/321/5
Another is we should consider to eliminate spurious variables. The sources are below
https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/jci-2017-0010/html
https://academic.oup.com/aje/article/177/4/292/147738?login=true
As a results, I am confused which procedures that I should follow.
Moreover, I am thinking that the procedures should be: fit model with all variables -> checking casual relationships -> variables selection (only for traditional modelling: Linear, Poisson, negative binomial, zero inflated because machine learning algorithms themself do variable selection) -> predictive error assessment. Would it be true?

Welcome to Cross Validated! There's also this extensive discussion arguing against automated model selection. "Spurious" variables might best be identified by applying subject-matter understanding. I'd recommend that you look at Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies, in particular Chapter 4, "Multivariable Modeling Strategies," on how to get the most information from your data without over-fitting. Although presented in the context of regression models, the principles apply more broadly.

I presume that casual is a repeated typo for causal. A deeper question is that most of the methods or criteria you mention have nothing to do with causality so far as I can see.

@EdM thank you for your comment. I will read carefully to eliminate my confused points for examining causal inference.

@NickCox I am sorry for the typo it would be causal. Your comment on my methods is true. This is the reason why I am confused about whether I need to use these methods if I would like to focus on causal inference.

I think that I have addressed this question in my answer to another of your questions. For how to build regression models, consult Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies, particularly Chapter 4. Causal inference requires going beyond regression models, see Hernán and Robins.

@EdM yes, I have seen your answer. Thank you for your quick response
